# getLbClient()' has protected access in 'org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient

Tags: java, solr, solrj, solrcloud

i have upgraded solr version in my java code from v8 to v9.2.0 and getting error as 'getLbClient()' has protected access in 'org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient' in the java method

```
public Version getVersion() {
    // Concurrent access might cause multiple fetches, but who cares?
    if (null != version) {
        return version;
    }
    // TODO reconcile w/ repo service version

    // Ensure connected so that we can get the live nodes
    // If our connection attempt fails here, we'll try again next time we're asked
    solrClient.connect();

    // Note that we ignore the possibility of a cluster containing nodes of different versions

    // We have to use this crazy scheme because CommonParams.ADMIN_PATHS
    // does not contain /admin/info/system

    // Problem is that CloudSolrClient insists on putting a collection in the URL
    // for paths not in ADMIN_PATHS, so we instead circumvent and use the underlying LBHttpSolrClient

    // See code in CloudSolrClient.sendRequest(SolrRequest request, List<String> inputCollections)

    final List<String> liveNodeUrls = (List<String>) solrClient.getClusterState().getLiveNodes();

    final GenericSolrRequest genericSolrRequest = new GenericSolrRequest(
          GET,
          "/admin/info/system",
          null);

    final LBSolrClient.Req rawRequest = new LBSolrClient.Req(
          genericSolrRequest,
          liveNodeUrls);

    final LBSolrClient.Rsp rawResponse;
    try {
        rawResponse = solrClient.getLbClient().request(rawRequest);
    }
    catch (final SolrServerException | IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    final NamedList<?> luceneProps = (NamedList<?>) ((LBSolrClient.Rsp) rawResponse).getResponse().get("lucene");
    version = Version.valueOf(String.valueOf(luceneProps.get("solr-spec-version")));
    return version;
}
```

I got few other errors as well but now stuck on this error only 'getLbClient()' has protected access in 'org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient'

Comment: Why do you need to access it? `solrClient.request` should be enough.